# Assign post values of multiple checkbox inputs to a PHP variable and separate by comma

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using `PDO`, `foreach` and `echo` to generate some form inputs with data from a database, the output for this example will look slimier to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>Google
<input type="checkbox" value="2">Amazon
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked>Microsoft
```

This is being used in a form which is posted to the same page.
I want to grab this data and store it in a database using a PHP variable so when the checkbox is checked the value is assigned to it like this:

```
// output
$data = '1,3';
```

please note, the checkbox is checked by the users and the data used here is just an example, i want the form to be able to collect the right data by user input.

Comment: Use an array in html and you will have an array in php: `<input type="checkbox[]" value=...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give name to checkbox as an array, so when you submit form you will get an array of checkbox values in the array which checkboxes are checked then you can implode that array with `,` comma separated.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="1" checked>Google
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="2">Amazon
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="3" checked>Microsoft
```

After submitting form you have to get values like below code.

```
$data = implode(",", $_POST['checkboxname']);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery:
for example:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">Google
<input type="checkbox" value="2">Amazon
<input type="checkbox" value="3">Microsoft
<button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click',function(){
        var cboxVal = [];

        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i){       
                cboxVal[i] = $(this).val();
        });

        $.ajax({
            url     : 'insert_data.php',
            method  : 'POST',
            data    : {cval:cboxVal},
            dataType: 'text',
            async   : false,
            success : function(){
                        alert('data inserted!');
            }   
    }); 
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cval'])){
    $cval_raw = $_POST['cval'];

    for($i =0; $i<count($cval_raw);$i++){
        $cval = $cval_raw[$i];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO db_name(table_name) VALUES('$cval')" or die('cannot insert');

        $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    }    
}
?>
```